# How do i render a .js file on a button click in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I am making an application in electron using reactjs. O am using reactstrap as well. I have the main page named as app.js and want to go to a different page on a button click.

Background: The main page is called app.js and I want to go to an info page named info.js

info.js is exported as shown below

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';

class Info extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      code is here
    );
  }
}

export default Info;
```

App.js is as follows as well

```
import React from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'reactstrap';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      code is here
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) setup Info.js as a route then use a Link to get to it, here is a [good example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) by React Training.